# Issue with the control "m" characters while loading the data using oet table

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, plsql

I have a couple of files in unix path through i am loading the data into the oracle 11g database using oracle external table but when i load the data we are facing the issue with the control "m" characters .We are manually removing the control m characters from the each column is there any alternate option to exclude the control m characters while loading the data using oracle external table.

Thank you.

Comment: When working with files across operating systems this is one of the most common things to be aware of. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline.

Answer (score 1):

I face similar problem before and I convert the files into unix format before loading the data in oracle. below is the command.

```
dos2unix <file>
```

sample below:

```
[oracle@db3 ~]$ dos2unix vj.out 
dos2unix: converting file vj.out to UNIX format ...
```

This is my reference: https://chrisjean.com/convert-dos-formatted-files-to-unix-format-in-ubuntu-and-centos/.  If you need to install it, the link has an instruction to install it. `sudo apt-get install tofrodos`